# ExpandableListView does not overlap content below it

Tags: android, expandablelistview

Here's the code for my XML. The expandable listView does not overlap but pushes the content down in space which makes the layout look very ugly.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" >

    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
                android:clickable="true"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:contentDescription="@string/logo"
                android:src="@drawable/smart_kids_logo"
                android:onClick="home" />

        <TextView
                android:clickable="true"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.25"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                android:text="@string/home"
                android:onClick="home" />

        <TextView
                 android:clickable="true"
                 android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                 android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                 android:layout_width="0dp"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_weight="0.33"
                 android:text="@string/about"
                 android:onClick="about" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout 
            android:baselineAligned="false"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp">

            <ExpandableListView 
                android:id="@+id/LDBasics"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.25"/>

            <ExpandableListView 
                android:id="@+id/AgesStages"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.25"/>

            <ExpandableListView 
                android:id="@+id/GuideToAction"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.25"/>

            <ExpandableListView 
                android:id="@+id/ParentsCommunity"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.25"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:baselineAligned="false"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent">


        <LinearLayout 
            android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.3"
            android:background="#83D6D4"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:text="@string/QuickLinks"
                android:textSize="14sp" />

             <TextView
                 android:clickable="true"
                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                 android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                 android:text="@string/NewToLD"
                 android:textSize="10sp" />

              <TextView 
                android:clickable="true"
                android:textSize="10sp"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/dyslexia"/>

               <TextView 
                android:clickable="true"
                android:textSize="10sp"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/adhd"/>

                <TextView 
                android:clickable="true"
                android:textSize="10sp"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/nld"/>

                <TextView
                android:clickable="true"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                android:text="@string/executiveFunction"
                android:textSize="10sp" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout 
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.7"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin">

            <ImageView 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:contentDescription="@string/logo"
                android:src="@drawable/home_page_image"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/HomePageCaption"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                android:text="@string/HomePageText"
                android:textSize="12sp" />

        </LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

When I expand the listView, it pushes all the other textViews down rather than overlapping them.
How do I fix this? Should I be using the overscroll property?

Comment: Try to given weight=1 to parent layout of all ExpandableListView.

Comment: No that does not work. It creates an empty space where the list expands and it yet doesnt overlap the underlying content